# Owl carousel dynamic data binding with json

Tags: jquery, json, owl-carousel

I want to bind my data to owl carousel. I can bind it with json data path. 
Like this:

```
   $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    jsonPath: 'json/customData.json',
    jsonSuccess: customDataSuccess});

   function customDataSuccess(data) {
    var content = "";
    for (var i in data["items"]) {
    var img = data["items"][i].img;
    var alt = data["items"][i].alt;
    content += "<img src=\"" + img + "\" alt=\"" + alt + "\">"
    }
    $("#owl-demo").html(content);
   }
```

But, I am getting with ajax. I dont want get with json file. 
My code:

```
  jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "DetailSrv.asmx/GetDetails",
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: categoryID }), 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (sonuc) {
                jsonData = JSON.parse(sonuc.d);
                console.log(jsonData);
                var html = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                    var itemData = jsonData[i];

                }
            }});
```

How can i use this jsonData on custonDataSuccess(data) function?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
I am using owl with mustache.js and I template the content in other way but well i guess this should work for You too.

```
$("#owl-demo").data('owlCarousel').addItem(content);
```